# How to get trending tweets about a location

Tags: api, twitter

I need to get trending tweets about a location. I am currently getting trending tweets from a given location using woeid but this is not what I need. I need to get trending tweets about a city like Paris. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: What have you already tried? Have you really found no way to look up WOEID?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the WOEID (Where On Earth ID) for Paris: 615702.
Also, the WOEID for France is 23424819. Read the official twitter documentation on "[GET trends/place](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/trends/place)." It explains what you need to know.